# unable to import requests in python on server

Tags: python, python-requests

i have a python script which uses requests module. I had installed requests on my machine and the script runs fine. Now I wanted to run this script on server so that it's always available(otherwise it requires my local machine to be running that script all the time, for it to function)

I installed requests (via `pip install requests`) and when I do `pip freeze`, it does show requests as one of the installed modules. but when I run the script, I get an error

`import requests 
ImportError: No module named requests`

it is unable to find requests even when I try importing it in python shell on server, gives the same error - `No module named requests`.

How do I get this going - TIA

**EDIT**: It was an issue with the version difference - I was trying on python2.6(which happened to be the default on the server) and requests module was for 2.7. After trying to run the script using python2.7, it worked just fine.

Comment: Do you run `pip` and/or your script in a virtualenv?

Comment: Are you running your script ina  `virtualenv`?

Comment: that I'm a total n00b, i already knew but this is a new revelation. The issue was with the python version running on the server. It was running 2.6 as default -- whereas (from what I can guess) requests works for 2.7

I ran python2.7 and then tried importing requests, it worked fine. and the script now works fine. Gah, I have a lot lot lot to learn.

Comment: @schwobaseggl & MrPyCharm - thanks for trying to help, I was able to fix this(for now, without much understanding) by running python2.7 instead of default on my server(which was 2.6) and requests worked fine. Can someone please close this question

Comment: @MrPyCharm & schwobaseggl no, i'm not running it in a virtualenv

Comment: @awkward101 You can remove your own question. Or you can answer it yourself;) it does not strike me as a pointless question. You might consider rephrasing the question in a more general way, e.g. it could have been any pip-installed module, it being `requests` having nothing to do with issue.

Comment: @schwobaseggl ok, will do, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with the python versions. My server's default was 2.6 and requests was 2.7 - tried running python2.7 and then it worked. Closing this.